# oracle specific column accepts a specific format of character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

In oracle database I have a table 'emp_table' that has a column 'eTIN' which is NVARCHAR2(12). I want to modify it to accept only 0-9 as character. I dont want to modify is as number type. So that next time I will have scope to modify it further. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the CHECK constraint like this:

```
CHECK (regexp_like(myCol,'^[[:digit:]]+$'))
```

Something like

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE myTable(
  2  myCol VARCHAR2(12),
  3  CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (regexp_like(myCol,'^[[:digit:]]+$'))
  4  )
  5  /
```

And if the table is already created then simply ALTER the table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (regexp_like(myCol,'^[[:digit:]]+$'))
```